# Explanation on TSP Algorithms

Tags: algorithm, hungarian-algorithm

I am currently trying to learn more about the Travelling Salesman Problem (TSP).
I have found a few heuristic algorithms from the internet that is about solving this, such as the ant colony optimization, lin-kernighan, pairwise exchange and etc.

On the other hand, there are also other algorithms such as help-karp and branch and bound algorithm.

They mentioned that they solving TSP, but they seems to be finding the shortest path from point A to point G, via whatever points in between, that could shorten the path.

In this case, i am thinking that they are pretty similar to Dijiktra algorithm...

On top of that, some of these algorithms are using weightage to calculate. What is the usual weightage they use ? is it the distance ? and how do they actually obtain all these information?

From my understanding, TSP is about needing to travel to a few specified locations, and from and back to the same point of origin, isn't it ?

Algorithms such as Hungarian Algorithms seems to answer the TSP more appropriately, isn't it ?

However, i can't find much research paper on this algorithm.

Please advise.

Comment: Your question really really shows some misconceptions and lack of knowledge. I'm very sure, even wiki's article on the TSP should clear things up. The first step: do understand what the TSP really is! Dijiktra and the Assignment-problem / Hungarian-algorithm can't help. And to be honest: A google-scholar search will get you a alot of research-papers (some being free to access). Apart from that, this question is too broad and stated as that off-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

TSP is a famous NP hard(non-polynomial) problem.
The issue isn't that we don't know a solution to it, but that all solution are O(N!) complexity. Lots of algorithms do many smart things to cut down on obviously bad solutions but worst case (complete graph with equals weights) will run in O(N!).

Dijkstra is a polynomial algorithm. If you can make it solve TSP you are up for world-wide scientific awards (true since 1930s).

For references you can start with the ones on wikipedia.